# Couldn't able to update listview after onActivityResult();

Tags: android, listview

I did try notifyDataSetChanged() in CustomAdapter and also inside separate thread but not be able to update listview.

I have application in which I am getting contact name and number from contact list and storing into sqlite, and getting data in listview by reading it.

My code as follows:

code of adapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomDataListModel> {


    ArrayList<CustomDataListModel> customDataListModels;
    Context context;
    int resource;

    public CustomListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<CustomDataListModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource,objects);
        this.customDataListModels = customDataListModels;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CustomDataListModel getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customcontact, null, true);
        }

        final CustomDataListModel customDataListModel=getItem(position);

        TextView Name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametxtl);
        TextView Number=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nutxtl);

        Name.setText(customDataListModel.getName());
        Number.setText(customDataListModel.getNumber());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

code of reading data and adding to customModel:

```
public void DataRead(){

        Cursor cursor=myhelper.getAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() ==0){
            ViewDataDialog("Error","Nothing found" );

            return;

        }
        StringBuffer stringBuffer= new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            customDataListModelList.add(new CustomDataListModel(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2)));
            stringBuffer.append("Id :"+ cursor.getString(0)+"\n");
            stringBuffer.append("Name :"+ cursor.getString(1)+"\n");
            stringBuffer.append("Number :"+ cursor.getString(2)+"\n");

        }

    }
```

code inside oncreate for init listView and adapter:

```
 DataRead();

customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.customcontact, customDataListModelList);
listView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

Code of onActivity result which called whenever selecting contact and responsible for storing data in database:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (REQUEST_CODE_ADDRESS_BOOK):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
                    uriContact = data.getData();
                    DataAdd(getDisplayName(),getPhNumber());
                    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.invalidate();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure it is right way or not but i tried to using thread and calling this method in onCreate.

```
 public void threadMethod(){

        ListUpdateThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!ListUpdateThread.isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        ListUpdateThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: You do not need `threadMethod` and `invalidate()` and `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` . Only call `customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and make sure `customDataListModelList` has the data ..

Comment: why you want notifydataSetChanged on OnActivityResult?

Comment: yes Followed  your advise and able to update by adding one line DataRead() inside onActivityResult() but only problem is it's adding whole record again , i will solve that , thank you for short and logical ans

Comment: @vasudev Onactivity result called whenever i m selecting contact , so after selecting it redirecting to activity of listview so i need to display that contact

Comment: where is   startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_ADDRESS_BOOK);  called ?

Comment: @ Vasudev  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE_ADDRESS_BOOK);

Comment: @I did solve problem by only reading last record of database and while reading passing to the customDataListModelList , and then calling  customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); wrote this code inside onActivityResult().

Answer (score 0):

hope it will work for you.

customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();